# JavaScript: Declare variable inside object declaration

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to declare variables in JavaScript inside an object declaration? I'm looking for something similar to

```
var myObject = {
    myLabel: (var myVariable)
};
```

instead of having to write

```
var myVariable;
var myObject = {
    myLabel: myVariable
};
```

**EDIT**

I want this in the context of Node.JS. This is what I have:

```
var server = {};
var database = {};
var moar = {};

module.exports = {
    server: server,
    database: databse,
    moar: moar
};

doStuffAsync(function callback() {
    // Populate variables
    server = stuff();
    database = stuff2();
});
```

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: myObject.myLabel would be undefined anyway, just like myObject.yourLabel, so what's the point?

Comment: Edited question to clarify why I want this.

Comment: why don't you pass `module.exports` to your doStuffAsync function so that you can set `server` and `database` directly at that object?

Comment: The only reason I can think of doing this is to save **one line** of code. If you're worried about the number of lines of code, look into minification instead of destroying your readability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to scope a variable inside an object you can use IIFE (immediately invoked function expressions)

```
var myObject = {
    a_variable_proxy : (function(){ 
        var myvariable = 'hello'; 
        return myvariable; 
    })()
};
```

Comment: sould be `a_variable_proxy : (function(){ var myvariable; return myvariable })()` otherwise it is a syntax error

Comment: Need to remove the semi-colon :)

Comment: Maybe that's what the OP is looking for. But technically the variable is not scoped to the object as you said, it's scoped to the IIFE.

Comment: @bfavaretto but since it returns the variable, it can be accessed within the class. (new reply to an old comment, but hope it will help a new comer.)

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a value to a key directly.

If you now have:

```
var myVariable = 'some value';
var myObject = {
    myLabel: myVariable
};
```

you can replace it with:

```
var myObject = {
    myLabel: 'some value'
};
```

Comment: That is something he/she was trying to avoid.